# Dart - setting time to make unit testing easier

Tags: dart

Is  there any way of setting the system time in dart to a known value.

This would make writing unit tests far easier.

(the Joda api in Java allows one to set the system time!)

Comment: If time was an explicit concept of your model you wouldn't need to do this.

Comment: Obviously a strategy like that can help. So can having a DateTime Factory class that you use to create DateTime instances, which then can be mocked.I was hoping there would be a build in way of solving this common testing problem

Comment: How is time used in your objects or process?

Comment: I don't think changing the system time is a good strategy to solve this problem. This way two such tests running simultaneously would break each other. Abstracting and mocking `new DateTime.now()` would be a much better strategy.

Comment: There is also an open bug to allow for mocking the system time - so that you don't need to explicitly change every call to DateTime.now() https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16762

Answer (score 1):

You cannot easily set the time for your unit tests in Dart if your code uses the [`DateTime.now` constructor](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/DateTime/DateTime.now.html).  In some languages, you can just intercept basically any calls and return whatever you want (for example, JavaScript). This is not possible in Dart.

There is an issue tracking this in the `dart-lang` repo[(Code that uses DateTime.now is untestable #28985)](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/28985) .

The crux of the problem is explained well [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49984896): There is no general way to intercept static method calls including constructors.

There are some workarounds, though they all require some changes to your code.

The simplest option is that instead of calling directly `DateTime.now`, you inject the "now" date into your function or class, and in a case where the "now" date is not provided, you fallback to calling `DateTime.now`. This makes your code slightly inconvenient to write, but it's now testable.

The other option is to come up with an abstraction that works for your case, for example, if your class is `MyClass`, you could create a method

```
class MyClass {
  DateTime getCurrentTime() => DateTime.now();
}
```

Now, somewhere in your class you can call the `getCurrentTime` method instead of calling `DateTime.now` directly. Then, you can extend this class in your tests to intercept the current time, and use this variant in your unit tests:

```
class MyConfigurableDateClass extends MyClass {
  DateTime getCurrentTime() => currentTime;

  DateTime currentTime;

  void setCurrentTime(DateTime time) => currentTime = time;
}
```

This version already makes the "now" time configurable for each test case, which is necessary if your logic depends on the time.

If you don't need this configurability, and the only thing that your test needs is a fixed date, you can simplify it further:

```
class MyFixedDateClass extends MyClass {
  DateTime getCurrentTime() => DateTime(1999, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

I like this approach because it leaves the original code simple and expressive, the only change is that we call `getCurrentTime` instead of `DateTime.now`, while at the same time, you can configure the time either once per test suite or many times for different test cases.